# Problems reading file from ddms in android?

Tags: android, file, ddms

The file i want to open is located in the file:

```
/data/data/MY_PACKAGE/files/samplefile.txt
```

I have pulled the file from ddms and the desired content is in it

I just want to get the text file in order to parse it..

I tried the following:

```
File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
//Get the text file
File xmlFile = new File(sdcard,"samplefile.txt");
```

but no joy...

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

Use `getFilesDir()`, not `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`, to get at the root of internal storage, where your file resides.

Answer (score 0):

In order to open a file stored within your applications private directory you must use [openFileInput(String fileName)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileInput%28java.lang.String%29). This will return a FileInputStream that you can then work with.